# Need to dynamically set the impersonate password value

Tags: c#, impersonation

I've read a few posts on impersonation but I'm not sure I completely understand how it works.

We have an existing web app running under IIS. We are using identity impersonate in the Web.config file for the database connection id as follows:

```
<identity impersonate="true" userName="MY_DBID" password="mypassword"
xdt:Transform="SetAttributes(impersonate,userName,password)" />
```

We are now trying to remove the clear-text hardcoded passwords from the application.

We have a third party software package that stores/manages account passwords.  I am calling that service from Application_Start in Global.asax.cs and obtaining the password for MY_DBID.

Is there a way I can pass/use this password in the password="mypassword" parm of the Web.config impersonation?  Other suggestions are welcome.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using an Impersonator class scheme documented at the link below. Thanks http://www.codeproject.com/articles/10090/

Answer (score 1):

The identity tag is running your entire web application as that user. `Application_Start` is too late, as the framework has already attempted to impersonate that user. You are not going to be able to accomplish this with code in your application.

You should [store your impersonation credentials in encrypted form](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72wdk8cc%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) in the registry as per the remarks section of this page on the `<identity>` element.

Comment: Says the link is no longer available

Comment: Corrected. Why does MS have to support non-version-specific pages on some links and not on others...

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion.  I began to read up on that - but we were trying to avoid the extra step. The third-party package we use has the ability to change an account's password periodically or on-request.  So we were trying to avoid having to re-encrypt when this happens.